# Getting the last Api data from a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api, items

I have a covid 19 Api in my site, but i want it to give only the last data, every day the array keeps getting bigger, how do i fix this?

```
// Api Link+Key
$.getJSON("https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/netherlands", 

// Function to extract data from the Api
function(data){
    console.log(data);

// connect a variable to the Api Path
    var covid_confirmed = data[231].Confirmed;
    var covid_active = data[231].Active;
    var covid_deaths = data[231].Deaths;
    var covid_date = data[231].Date;

// Make the variable an working variable for in html
$('.covid_confirmed').append(covid_confirmed);
$('.covid_active').append(covid_active);
$('.covid_deaths').append(covid_deaths);
$('.covid_date').append(covid_date);


});
```

This is how the array will form:
[Picture of RAW Api data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJuew.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just select the latest value of the array

```js
// Api Link+Key
$.getJSON("https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/netherlands", 

// Function to extract data from the Api
function(data){
    console.log(data);

// connect a variable to the Api Path
    var covid_confirmed = data[data.length-1].Confirmed;
    var covid_active = data[data.length-1].Active;
    var covid_deaths = data[data.length-1].Deaths;
    var covid_date = data[data.length-1].Date;

  // Make the variable an working variable for in html
  $("#confirmed").text(`confirmed: ${covid_confirmed}`);
  $("#active").text(`active: ${covid_active}`);
  $("#deaths").text(`deaths: ${covid_deaths}`);
  $("#date").text(`date: ${covid_date}`);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmed"></div>
<div id="active"></div>
<div id="deaths"></div>
<div id="date"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last record.

```
const lastRecord = data.pop();
or
const lastRecord = data[data.length-1];
```

why dont you give sorting and paging options for your api ? Another solution is create a route for the last report, something like `/latest-result`

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation for covid19api.com](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc#9739c95f-ef1d-489b-97a9-0a6dfe2f74d8) shows that you can add a `from` and `to`-parameter to the API call.

This lets you specify that you want only data since a given date, so you can for instance use the call

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/netherlands/status/confirmed?from=2020-09-08T23:00:00Z&to=2020-09-09T00:00:00Z")
```

To get only one array element with data from the 9th of September 2020